Comparing two samples with same number of observations and having same mean but different variances
Given two different set data samples have same mean and same number of observations; if their variances are same, what can be concluded? Also if both variances are different what can be concluded?
That's all that's written in the test question, there is no more detailed information. The question wasn't in English so I tried to translate it as best I could. I don't know what it means but it seems to be asking for general information on the effect of variance differences in comparing two different samples.

More precisely, this is a selection test question for statistician position in civil servant selection.

Please add the self-study tag.

Hey @Peter, OP added that. I mistakenly removed it; added now.

Honestly, this seems like a very poor question, fundamentally because one does not start by collecting data, then wonders what question it might answer, but instead one starts with a question, then collects data to see if it can help answer it.
As best as I can guess, because the question seems to hinge on equal vs. unequal variances, the first thing which came to mind was the the Behrens-Fisher problem. However, because we are told that the samples have "the same number of observations", this problem does not really manifest itself; this makes the question moot.
For example, say I wanted to run a t-test. With equal variances I would use the "vanilla" 2-sample t-test. But with unequal variances I would use a Welch t-test. But because $\bar x_1 = \bar x_2$, no t-test, of any flavor, will never return a significant result, no matter what the (equal or not) sample sizes. Not even $\alpha$% of the time. Why? Because the CI of the difference of means will always be centered on the observed difference of means which is 0... Note that more and more authors (e.g. here or here) recommend using the Welch t-test regardless of the variances (which, in all real-world samples, are never exactly equal).
But if I wanted to run a Mann-Whitney U test, even in the first case (equal means, variances and sample sizes), I could get a significant result (depending on the shape of the distributions). And in the 2nd case (unequal variances), I would use a Brunner-Munzel test, and I may be able to find significant results. Note that here too some authors (e.g. here) recommend to use Brunner Munzel regardless of the variances.
Just for fun, I decided to ask ChatGPT about the first case. This is ChatGPT's final summary" "In summary, the samples have the same central tendency and variability but may differ in the underlying distribution or arrangement of values.". I did not have high expectations, but this is about as non-insightful as it gets. I did not bother asking about the 2nd case.
Note that, for 2 samples to have the same mean, we can confidently conclude that they have been artificially created (they are not real world samples); even more so when the variances are also equal. Maybe that is the answer?

I would like to suggest that the focus on testing  might miss the point of the question.  Certainly there's no issue of testing means here.  For that reason I think this answer is at best tangential.  One could make a case for a discussion of comparing variances; but the open-ended, general framing suggests the prompt is trying to gauge how attuned the respondent is to the usefulness, meaning, interpretation, and exploitation of variability and uncertainty.

I would go further and say that indeed the question hinges on equality or not of variability, and its implications. One could say that in 1 case, the samples have the same spread/variability, and not in the 2nd case. But that is tautological. And is kind of what ChatGPT answered. Less tautological is that homoscedasticity is a key assumption of many tests; I listed only 2. But now I am speculating about what one might do with the data, and that quickly becomes moot. So my choices are trivial tautology vs. moot speculation. Hence, this is a poor question. Or maybe I am failing the question?

Interview questions are designed to get the applicant to open up and volunteer ideas, perhaps revealing their thought processes, experience, and approaches to situations that might not be as well-defined as textbook settings. (That's why such questions are usually a poor fit for this site btw.) I think one key to answering them is to begin by explaining how you interpret the question and why, stating what you think might be of importance to the interviewer, and moving on to offer a plan of analysis--but not necessarily a solution. Showing awareness of alternative interpretations can be a plus.
